# Otherwise on StateProvider

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

Using angular-ui-router, How can I use the [otherwise method](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$routeProvider) on [$stateProvider](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki) or how can I use it at all ?

Comment: what are you trying to do? (Please note that I don't fully understand `$stateProvider.otherwise`, so it'll help me out)

Answer (score 124, accepted):

You can't use only `$stateProvider`.

You need to inject `$urlRouterProvider` and create a code similar to:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/otherwise');
```

The `/otherwise` url must be defined on a state as usual:

```
 $stateProvider
    .state("otherwise", { url : '/otherwise'...})
```

See this link where [ksperling explains](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/89)

Comment: You can actually use `$stateProvider`. It's less work if you just want to display a template, but not redirect. I prefer @juan-hernandez's answer.

Comment: does the value passed to `otherwise` (in this case `'/otherwise'`) have to match the name of the state (the first parameter to `.state`) or the value for `url` option?

Comment: This is now deprecated - see [answer from @babyburger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52127305/769137)

Answer (score 83):

You can with `$stateProvider` using the **catch all syntax** (`"*path"`). You just need to add a state config at the bottom of your list like the following one:

```
$stateProvider.state("otherwise", {
    url: "*path",
    templateUrl: "views/error-not-found.html"
});
```

All the options are explained in https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#regex-parameters.

The nice thing of this option, as opposed to `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(...)`, is that you 're not forced to a location change.

Comment: could you please elaborate: `you're not forced to a location change`?

Comment: What he means is the url will stay what it was. So if the user goes to `/this/does/not/exist`, then the URL will stay that way in the address bar. The other solution will take you to `/otherwise`

Comment: I used your solution and it worked (I can keep the url that was not found which is great because I'm using http://luisfarzati.github.io/angulartics/ and this way I can also see navigation to pages that were not found) for cases when the url the user navigates to does not exist. However if I navigate to this url using $state.go('otherwise') inside a controller I lose the url. I navigate explicitly to this state when the user goes to an item's details page and the server returns 404 (for example if the item was deleted). Do you know of a way to fix this?

Comment: @pcatre you can use option location=false and the url won't change. Eg. $state.go('otherwise',{},{location:false})

Answer (score 36):

You can also manually inject $state into the otherwise function, which you can then navigate to a non-url state. This has the benefit of the browser not changing the addressbar, which is helpful for handling going back to a previous page.

```
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function ($injector, $location) {
        var $state = $injector.get('$state');

        $state.go('defaultLayout.error', {
            title: "Page not found",
            message: 'Could not find a state associated with url "'+$location.$$url+'"'
        });
    });
```

Comment: that solved my problem on how to check if we are mid-app or onload when otherwise is used - thank you so much :)

Comment: you saved my day !

Comment: Dont forget if you wanna minimize this u need $inject

Answer (score 4):

I just want to chime in on the great answers that are already provided. The latest version of `@uirouter/angularjs` marked the class `UrlRouterProvider` as deprecated.  They now recommend using `UrlService` instead.  You can achieve the same result with the following modification:

```
$urlService.rules.otherwise('/defaultState');
```

Additional methods: https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/1.0.16/interfaces/url.urlrulesapi.html

Answer (score 3):

Ok, the silly moment when you realize that the question you asked is already answered in the first lines of the sample code! Just take a look at the sample code.

```
       angular.module('sample', ['ui.compat'])
      .config(
        [        '$stateProvider', '$routeProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
        function ($stateProvider,   $routeProvider,   $urlRouterProvider) {
          $urlRouterProvider
            .when('/c?id', '/contacts/:id')
            .otherwise('/'); // <-- This is what I was looking for ! 


          ....
```

[Take a look here.](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/master/sample/index.html#L34)

Answer (score 0):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22235960/1175496) references `angular-route` asks about `ui-router`. The accepted answer uses the ["monolithic"](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/26) `$routeProvider`, which requires the `ngRoute` module (whereas `ui-router` needs the `ui.router` module)

The [highest-rated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27435414/1175496) uses `$stateProvider` instead, and says something like `.state("otherwise", { url : '/otherwise'... })`,
but I can't find any mention of "otherwise" in the [documentation it links](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki). However, I see that `$stateProvider` is mentioned [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17053297/1175496) where it says:

> You can't use only `$stateProvider`. You need to inject `$urlRouterProvider`

That's where my answer might help you. For me, it was sufficient to use `$urlRouterProvider` just like this:

```
 my_module
   .config([
    , '$urlRouterProvider'
    , function(
        , $urlRouterProvider){
            //When the url is empty; i.e. what I consider to be "the default"
            //Then send the user to whatever state is served at the URL '/starting' 
            //(It could say '/default' or any other path you want)
            $urlRouterProvider
                    .when('', '/starting');
                    //...
    }]);
```

My suggestion is consistent with the `ui-router` [documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#urlrouterprovider), ([this specific revision](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing/d8f2979284d69d84ac444fe4ef148373edc94ef2)), where it includes a similar use of the .`when(...)` method (the first call to the function):

```
app.config(function($urlRouterProvider){
  // when there is an empty route, redirect to /index   
  $urlRouterProvider.when('', '/index');

  // You can also use regex for the match parameter
  $urlRouterProvider.when(/aspx/i, '/index');
})
```