# getting data via $.ajax how can i do it the "angular" way. Does $http replace $.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs, angularjs-routing

here is my code.

```
.state("dynamic", {
        url: "/:name",
        controller : 'AppHomeCtrl',
        templateUrl: function (params){

            var myURL = params.name + '.html';

            var validPage = true;
            $.ajax({
                url: myURL,
                async: false })
            .done(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                if (data.toLowerCase().indexOf("doctype") >= 0) {
                    validPage = false;
                }
            })

            if (!validPage) {
                return 'error.html';
            } else {
                return params.name + '.html';

            }
        },
```

Is this possible to rewrite a state of a route (using angular-ui-routes) to get a page based on if the page gotten has a doctype or not?

the code above works perfectly.  but how can I replace $.ajax with $http  I must be missing something...

```
 $http.get(url).success(function(data) {
 if (data.toLowerCase().indexOf("doctype") >= 0) {
                validPage = false;
            }
 });
```

do I need to load $http somewhere higher up? etc.

Comment: Have you injected `$http`?

Comment: @snahor `.state` is configured in the `.config` block, and I'm not sure about the availability of services such as `$http` in that block.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#templates. In the last example, `$timeout` is injected and `templateProvider` is used instead of `templateUrl`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to use a service, such as `$http`, inside the `config` block.

It seems that what you're trying to do is handle requests for URLs that your application doesn't support. If you were using [`$routeProvider`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.$routeProvider) rather than `$stateProvider`, it would've been possible to route all unmatched URL requests to `.otherwise()`, but you can also mimic this behavior while using `$stateProvider`. See this stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17053297/604296) for more details on how to do that.