# Catch any urls using angularjs ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using Agularjs and ui-router in my application. I need to catch all urls except "signin" & "/" . All the urls must go to a state.

For example, the urls will be like

```
www.example.com/   // index
www.example.com/signin   // signin page

www.example.com/cars
www.example.com/sports
www.example.com/politics
```

My current setup is

```
 .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('index', {
        url: "/",
        templateUrl: 'partials/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'             
      })
      .state('signin', {
        url: "/signin",
        templateUrl: 'partials/signin',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'             
      })
      .state("otherwise", {
        url: "*path",
        templateUrl: 'partials/detail',
        controller: 'MainCtrl' 
       });
```

I also tried

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function($injector, $location) {
  $location.path($location.path());
})
```

But it doesnt load/show the page.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise` and route to a defined state which i called `detail` for your example:

```
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/detail");

    $stateProvider
      .state('index', {
        url: "/",
        templateUrl: 'partials/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'             
      })
      .state('signin', {
        url: "/signin",
        templateUrl: 'partials/signin',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'             
      })
      .state("detail", {
        url: "/detail",
        templateUrl: 'partials/detail',
        controller: 'MainCtrl' 
       });
```

Comment: Thanks.. but this will redirect any urls to /chat. I would like to keep the original url there itself. Is this possible ?

Comment: good question. the `*path` in your question seems to be the right way, as shown in `http://stackoverflow.com/a/18761391/675065`

Comment: @nish Works for me fine. The only thing you should have to modify about @Alp's code above is changing the url from `/detail` to `*path`.