# ui-router's $urlRouterProvider.otherwise with HTML5 Mode

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Consider the following slightly modified code from ui-router's wiki.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ui.router']);

myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    // for any unmatched url
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/state1");

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    // now set up the states
    $stateProvider
        .state('state1', {
            url: '/state1',
            templateUrl: "partials/state1.html"
        })
        .state('state1.list', {
            url: "/list",
            templateUrl: "partials/state1.list.html",
            controller: function($scope) {
                $scope.items = ["A", "List", "of", "Items"];
            }
        })
        .state('state2', {
            url: "/state2",
            templateUrl: "partials/state2.list.html",
            controller: function($scope) {
                $scope.things = ["a", "set", "of", "things"];
            }
        })
});
```

Running python 3's SimpleHttpServer, I get a `404 error` when trying to access: `http://localhost:8000/state1234324324`.

Why didn't `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/state1");` re-direct all unknown routes to `/state1`, which per this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16793724/otherwise-on-stateprovider), has a defined `state` associated with the `/state1` url?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because when you hit the server with urls like "/state123413", it will directly returns the 404 response (No routing at client side takes place).

What you need to do is to have a catchall route. e.g in express you can do

```
app.get('/*', function(req, res){
   res.render('defaulttemplate')   
}
```

This will force the routing on client side. Please see the ui router [faq](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode) for common servers to set the catchall route.

Comment: why does this not work properly with ui-router? my routes are not working since I added that fix, although the otherwise is now working...