# How to redirect user to default url

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using angular-ui-router with HTML5 mode set to false - I use hashbang. When user hits `mydomain.com` I need to redirect him to `mydomain.com/#/welcome`, how can I do that?

I've looked through ui-router source code and when `mydomain.com` is hit the `$location.path()` is `""` so this approach `.when("", "/welcome")` doesn't work since `.when(""` translates into this `/^$/` regex and when `""` is tested against this regex `null` is returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a viable solution:

```
appModule.run(['$location', function ($location) {

    if ($location.path() === "") {
        $location.path("/");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use $urlRouterProvider.otherwise to redirect to your welcome page if the current URL doesn't match any of your states.

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/welcome');
```

See this stack overflow question: [Otherwise on StateProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16793724/otherwise-on-stateprovider)

Comment: In my app I use `.otherwise` to redirect to `not found` page

Comment: check [my](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31338999/2545680) answer to this question if interested

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to show welcome.html you can do something like below

```
.when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'welcome.html',
                controller: 'homeCtrl'
            })
```

Else if you want to redirect user to mydomain.com/#/welcome you can use window.locations or you can handle it as the part of homeCtrl where you can redirect it using  $location.path('/welcome'); and below be route for it

```
.when('/welcome', {
                templateUrl: 'welcome.html',
                controller: 'welcomeCtrl'
            })
```

Comment: `.when('/'` won't trigger redirect if you hit `mydomain.com` in hashbang mode. It will be triggered if you hit `mydomain.com/#/`

Comment: check [my](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31338999/2545680) answer to this question if interested