# AngularJS force app to start from specific URL

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

I have a specific logic sequence in my app, and I want a simple way to force my app to start from the welcome page.
I am using this:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/pages/welcome');
```

the problem is that `otherwise` just play with the unknown URLs and redirect them to the `welcome`, whereas I want to redirect to the `welcome` in all cases, even in the registered states.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Otherwise on StateProvider](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16793724/otherwise-on-stateprovider)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply try `location.hash = '#/';` like the following:

```
angular.module('app', []).config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    location.hash = '#/';

    $stateProvider
        .state('welcome', {
            url        : '/pages/welcome',
            templateUrl: 'views/welcome.html',
            controller : 'WelcomeCtrl'
        });

    // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/pages/welcome');        
})
```

Comment: Oh, it's really simple, that's what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

i think you are redirecting to page not any `state`. You need to mredirect to state.

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/state1");
```

Comment: thanks @U R, in fact I already using this, but it dosnt work in the case I refresh an internal page

Comment: @MuhammadAmeer Check out this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16793724/otherwise-on-stateprovider/18761391#18761391

Comment: provide your code on planker .may be the problem is in other part of the code.