# Go to default route on page refresh with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-route

If I am at certain route, I would like to go back to default route if someone hits F5. How can I do this?

Comment: you could have `otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/default page'
      });` in your route configuration..

Comment: Not sure its clear enough - Probably the user change the route (http://yoursite.com/something) and he is not on the home page. so it make sense to refresh the url and to get the 'something' page template again

Comment: Check for some data you expect to be loaded and if it's not present change the location to the default page.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11542936/1886244 that might solve your problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS force app to start from specific URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34039989/angularjs-force-app-to-start-from-specific-url)