# $urlRouterProvider $stateProvider otherwise does not work

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

Hi below is my code for urlRouterProvider otherwise.

```
.config(function config($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/invalid');
$stateProvider.state('view', {
  url: '/view?{businessId:^[0-9]{1,20}$}',
  templateUrl: 'view/view.tpl.html',
  controller: 'ViewCtrl',
  controllerAs: 'vm' 
})
.state('otherwise', {
    url: '/invalid',
    templateUrl: 'view/view.error.tpl.html'
});
})
```

This is what i am expecting: 
1. if i go to view?businessId=12345 it should load the page without any issues
2. if i go to view?businessId=abcd it should re-direct it to the view.error.tpl.html

But instead, it does nothing if i enter the invalid url. 
I reffered to this post for help but none of the options really work    [Otherwise on StateProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16793724/otherwise-on-stateprovider)

Answer (score 2):

you can try this, without using the otherwise function:

```
$stateProvider.state('view', {
  url: '/view?{businessId:^[0-9]{1,20}$}',
  templateUrl: 'view/view.tpl.html',
  controller: 'ViewCtrl',
  controllerAs: 'vm' 
})
.state('otherwise', {
    url: '*path',
    templateUrl: 'view/view.error.tpl.html'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.config(function ($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('view', {
      url: '/view?{businessId:^[0-9]{1,20}$}',
      templateUrl: 'view/view.tpl.html',
      controller: 'ViewCtrl',
      controllerAs: 'vm' 
    })
    .state('otherwise', {
        url: '*path',
        templateUrl: 'view/view.error.tpl.html'
    });

})
```