# $urlRouterProvider.otherwise is not a function

Tags: angular-ui-router

I have this **app.js** file

```js
angular.module('myApp', [
  'myApp.version',
    'ui.router'
]).
config(['$locationProvider','$urlRouterProvider','$stateProvider', function($locationProvider,$stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider) {

   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/view1');
        

  $stateProvider
      .state('view1', {
        url: '/view1',
        templateUrl: 'partials/view1.html'
        //controller: 'view1.MainController'
      })
      .state('view2', {
        url: '/view2',
        templateUrl: 'partials/view2.html'
      })

      .state('view3', {
        url: '/view3',
        templateUrl: 'partials/view3.html'
      })

      .state('view4', {
        url: '/view4',
        templateUrl: 'partials/view4.html'
      });
}]);
```

I have included "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.1/angular-ui-router.min.js" CDN in my index.html file and it is getting loaded fine.

But even when it is loaded the console is giving an error as

**Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
TypeError: $urlRouterProvider.otherwise is not a function**

I tried removing this line and then test the code, but then it gives

**Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
TypeError: $stateProvider.state is not a function**

I have gone through the code multiple times but I am unable to identify the mistake/error.

(angular version is 1.5.8 and angular-ui-router version is 0.3.1 ,if that helps)

Please Help!

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16793724/otherwise-on-stateprovider)?

Comment: @heringer yeah i have seen this post.. i tried with $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/") .. still the same error.. i think it has something to do with the angular-ui-router that i am including..i dont think it is getting included in the dependency in the app.js file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You inverted the parameters: urlRouterProvider and stateProvider.

wrong order:

```
config(['$locationProvider', '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$stateProvider, $httpProvider) {
```

right order:

```
config(['$locationProvider','$urlRouterProvider','$stateProvider', function($locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$stateProvider, $httpProvider) {
```

You used that technique to avoid problems with minification, but the order of the "stringed-names" must be the same to the order of the function parameters.

I bet you know that and just mistyped.

Comment: how dumb of me to forget that and I spent hours trying to figure out the error.. :/